# How to call a function on renderedCallback() that have dependency on @api in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, d3

I am working on an LWC component that renders a d3 chart. I get the chart data from the parent component.

```
@api assetClassValue

renderedCallback() {
   this.initializeD3(this.assetClassValue);
}

initializeD3(data)
{
 // d3 implementation goes here
}
```

Here problem is,when `this.initializeD3(this.assetClassValue);` is called inside `renderedCallback()` at the time `assetClassValue` is not set.

Is there any way from which I can ensure, `assetClassValue` is set before calling the `this.initializeD3(this.assetClassValue);`?

Comment: Call it from the `@api` property's setter instead (turn the property into a getter/setter property). This form of property is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getters_setters). You may also want to call it from the `renderedCallback` but only if the API property is not `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I find to do this is

```
@api assetClassValue
formated = false;

renderedCallback() {
   if(this.assetClassValue != undefined && !this.formated)
   {
      this.initializeD3(this.assetClassValue);
      this.formated = true
   }
   
 }
 initializeD3(data)
 {
   // d3 implementation goes here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Phil's comment, it would look something like this.

```
_assetClassValue;

@api 
get assetClassValue() {
    return this._assetClassValue;
}

set assetClassValue(value) {
    this._assetClassValue = value;
}

renderedCallback() {
    if (this.assetClassValue) {
        this.initializeD3(this.assetClassValue);
    }
}

initializeD3(data)
{
 // d3 implementation goes here
}
```